# save state of radiobutton

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two radiobuttons - no and yes. And I want to save the state of the radio buttons. But the current situation is that the state of the radiobutton is yes or no after save. So if you select no and save and then return to the page then the state is still on yes. I have this in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.OgoneFuturePrice, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.ShowFuturePriceYes) @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Ogone.FutureProductPrice, true, new { @class = "FutureNewProductPrice" })
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.ShowFuturePriceNo)  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Ogone.FutureProductPrice, false, new { @class = "FutureNewProductPrice" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="NewProductPriceView">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ogone.NewProductPriceView, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
                <input type="text" pattern="\d+([\.,]\d{2})?" value="@Model.Ogone.NewProductPriceView"
                       name="@Html.NameFor(model=>model.Ogone.NewProductPriceView)" class="form-control"
                       id="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Ogone.NewProductPriceView).ToString().Replace('.','_')"
                       placeholder="@Resources.Entity.Product.OgoneProductPricePlaceholder" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ogone.NewProductPriceView)


            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ogone.NewProductPriceDateView, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
                <input type="text" value="@Model.Ogone.NewProductPriceDateView"
                       id="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Ogone.NewProductPriceDateView).ToString().Replace('.','_')"
                       class="form-control datepicker"
                       name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Ogone.NewProductPriceDateView)"
                       data-val="true"
                       data-pattern="@ViewHelper.GetJSLocaleDateFormat()"
                       data-val-checknewproductpricedate="@Resources.Entity.Product.OgoneNoNewPriceDate"
                       data-val-validatenewproductpricedate="@Resources.Entity.Product.OgoneInvalidNewPriceDate" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ogone.NewProductPriceDateView)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $.validator.addMethod("checknewproductpricedate", function (val, el) {
                if ($("#Ogone_NewProductPriceView").val().length != 0)
                    return val.length != 0;

                return true;
            });

            $.validator.addMethod("validatenewproductpricedate", function (val, el) {
                // Checken of de datum in de toekomst ligt...
                var v = getDateFromInput(val, el);

                return (v > new Date());
            });

            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("checknewproductpricedate");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("validatenewproductpricedate");
        })(jQuery);

    </script>

</div>

@if (Model.Ogone.FutureProductPrice == false) {

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#NewProductPriceView').hide();
        });


    </script>

}
```

this as javascript:

```
$(".FutureNewProductPrice").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "True") {
            $('#NewProductPriceView').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#NewProductPriceView').hide();
    }
   });
```

and this as logic:

```
 internal void Deserialize(EditProductModel model)
        {
            XDocument settings = XDocument.Parse(model.Product.PaymentSettings);

            float price;
            XElement settingsElement = settings.Root.Element("productprice");
            if (settingsElement != null &&
                float.TryParse(settingsElement.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out price))
                model.Ogone.productPrice = price;

            settingsElement = settings.Root.Element("newproductprice");
            if (settingsElement != null) {
                XElement newPriceElement = settingsElement.Element("productprice");
                if (newPriceElement != null &&
                    float.TryParse(newPriceElement.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out price))
                    model.Ogone.newProductPrice = price;

                newPriceElement = settingsElement.Element("effectivedate");
                DateTime dt;
                if (newPriceElement != null &&
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(newPriceElement.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                    model.Ogone.newProductPriceDate = dt;

                XElement futureProductPrice = settings.Root.Element("FutureProductPrice");
                if (futureProductPrice != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(futureProductPrice.Value))
                    FutureProductPrice = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(futureProductPrice.Value);
                else
                    FutureProductPrice = true;
            }
        }
```

and this is responsible for the radiobuttons:

```
 XElement futureProductPrice = settings.Root.Element("FutureProductPrice");
                if (futureProductPrice != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(futureProductPrice.Value))
                    FutureProductPrice = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(futureProductPrice.Value);
                else
                    FutureProductPrice = true;
```

But everytime what you choose(yes or no) , it is always:

```
  FutureProductPrice = true;
```

And this is the serialize method:

```
internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model)
        {
            XDocument settings = new XDocument(new XElement("settings"));

            settings.Root.Add(new XElement("productprice", model.Ogone.productPrice.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));




            if (newProductPrice.HasValue) {
                if (!newProductPriceDate.HasValue)
                    throw new Exception("No date set for new product price");

                settings.Root.Add(
                     new XElement("newproductprice",
                         new XElement("productprice", model.Ogone.newProductPrice.Value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                         new XElement("effectivedate", model.Ogone.newProductPriceDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                          new XElement("FutureProductPrice", FutureProductPrice )
                     )
                 );
            }

            return settings.ToString(SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);
        }
```

I just try this in the serialize method:

```
string IsCheckPDf = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["model.Ogone.FutureProductPrice"];
                FutureProductPrice = IsCheckPDf.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I try something like this:

```
  XElement futureProductPrice = settings.Root.Element("FutureProductPrice");
                 futureProductPrice.SetAttributeValue("FutureProductPrice", true);
                 if (futureProductPrice != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(futureProductPrice.Value) && FutureProductPrice == false)
                    FutureProductPrice = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(futureProductPrice.Value);
                    //FutureProductPrice = true;
                else
                    FutureProductPrice = true;
```

But then I get this message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On this line:

```
futureProductPrice.SetAttributeValue("FutureProductPrice", true);
```

If I do this:

```
 XElement futureProductPrice = settings.Root.Element("FutureProductPrice");
                 futureProductPrice.SetValue("FutureProductPrice");
                 if (futureProductPrice != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(futureProductPrice.Value) && FutureProductPrice == false)
                    FutureProductPrice = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(futureProductPrice.Value);
                    //FutureProductPrice = true;
                else
                    FutureProductPrice = true;
```

I get this:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on this line:

```
 futureProductPrice.SetValue("FutureProductPrice");
```

if I do it like this:

```
  XElement futureProductPrice = settings.Root.Element("FutureProductPrice");
                futureProductPrice.SetValue("true");

                 if (futureProductPrice != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(futureProductPrice.Value))
                    FutureProductPrice = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(futureProductPrice.Value);

                else
                    FutureProductPrice = true;
```

I also get this warning:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is the complete class:

```
public class OgoneSettings
    {
        [Display(Name = "OgoneProductPrice", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string ProductPriceView
        {
            get { return this.productPrice.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture); }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
                    this.productPrice = 0;
                    return;
                }
                float p;
                string inp = value.Replace(',', '.');
                if (!float.TryParse(inp, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out p))
                    throw new Exception("Invalid price: " + value);

                this.productPrice = p;
            }
        }

        /* Checkout id wordt bepaald door de omgeving: Production of Test.
        [Display(Name = "OgoneCheckoutId", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string CheckoutId { get; set; }
        */
        [Display(Name = "NewProductPrice", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        public string NewProductPriceView
        {
            get
            {
                return this.newProductPrice.HasValue ? this.newProductPrice.Value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) : "";
            }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
                    this.newProductPrice = null;
                    return;
                }
                float p;
                string inp = value.Replace(',', '.');
                if (!float.TryParse(inp, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out p))
                    throw new Exception("Invalid price: " + value);

                this.newProductPrice = p;
            }
        }

        private float? newProductPrice;
        private float productPrice;
        private DateTime? newProductPriceDate;

        public bool FutureProductPrice { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "NewProductPriceDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]
        [NewProductPriceValidation(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product), ErrorMessageResourceName = "OgoneNoNewPriceDate")]
        [DateTimeValidation(SenecaFormsServer.SfsHelpers.ValidationType.FutureDate, null, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product), ErrorMessageResourceName = "OgoneInvalidNewPriceDate")]
        public string NewProductPriceDateView
        {
            get
            {
                return newProductPriceDate == null ? "" :
                    newProductPriceDate.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
            }
            set
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
                    newProductPriceDate = null;
                    return;
                }
                string pattern = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace(' ', '-').Replace('/', '-').Replace('.', '-');
                string clientValue = value.Replace(' ', '-').Replace('/', '-').Replace('.', '-');

                DateTime dt;
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(clientValue, pattern, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                    throw new Exception("Invalid date: " + value);

                newProductPriceDate = dt;
            }
        }


        internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model)
        {
            XDocument settings = new XDocument(new XElement("settings"));

            settings.Root.Add(new XElement("productprice", model.Ogone.productPrice.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));  




            if (newProductPrice.HasValue) {
                if (!newProductPriceDate.HasValue)
                    throw new Exception("No date set for new product price");




                settings.Root.Add(
                     new XElement("newproductprice",
                         new XElement("productprice", model.Ogone.newProductPrice.Value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                         new XElement("effectivedate", model.Ogone.newProductPriceDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                          new XElement("futureProductPrice", true )
                     )
                 );
            }


            return settings.ToString(SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);
        }


        internal void Deserialize(EditProductModel model)
        {
            XDocument settings = XDocument.Parse(model.Product.PaymentSettings);           

            float price;
            XElement settingsElement = settings.Root.Element("productprice");
            if (settingsElement != null &&
                float.TryParse(settingsElement.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out price))
                model.Ogone.productPrice = price;

            settingsElement = settings.Root.Element("newproductprice");
            if (settingsElement != null) {
                XElement newPriceElement = settingsElement.Element("productprice");
                if (newPriceElement != null &&
                    float.TryParse(newPriceElement.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out price))
                    model.Ogone.newProductPrice = price;

                newPriceElement = settingsElement.Element("effectivedate");
                DateTime dt;
                if (newPriceElement != null &&
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(newPriceElement.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                    model.Ogone.newProductPriceDate = dt;


               XElement futureProductPrice = settings.Root.Element("FutureProductPrice");

                 if (futureProductPrice != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(futureProductPrice.Value))
                        //futureProductPrice.SetValue("false");
                    FutureProductPrice = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(futureProductPrice.Value);

                else
                    FutureProductPrice = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class NewProductPriceValidation : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public NewProductPriceValidation()
        {


        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            OgoneSettings o = validationContext.ObjectInstance as OgoneSettings;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(o.NewProductPriceView))
                return null;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.NewProductPriceDateView))
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use cache to save the status or try to store the status in a log file.

Comment: @Jaffer. I realy dont understand what you are saying. Sorry

Comment: can you clarify me the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: The other properies are saving correctly. But only the state of the radio button is not saving. That is the exact problem.

Comment: FutureProductPrice is null

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment on the original question I'll have to write this here as an answer: Since you're getting a null result for FutureProductPrice, wouldn't that mean the :

```
if (futureProductPrice != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(futureProductPrice.Value))
```

condition is never verified and therefore 'futureProductPrice.Value' is not set?

Try editing this part of your code by replacing FutureProductPrice with true, like so:

```
settings.Root.Add(
                 new XElement("newproductprice",
                     new XElement("productprice", model.Ogone.newProductPrice.Value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                     new XElement("effectivedate", model.Ogone.newProductPriceDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                      new XElement("FutureProductPrice", true )
                 )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answare. That is correct. But how to set the value? I edit the post

Comment: Have you tried using the XElement.SetAttributeValue [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: No, but where to use that? Thank you

Comment: Right after creating your `xElement futureProductPrice` you should set the value of the Element. I'm sorry I think SetAttributeValue isn't what you need. What you want to use would be [xElement.setValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to set your element's value to true or false.

Comment: Use `futureProductPrice.SetValue` instead of `futureProductPrice.SetAttributeValue`. I'm sorry for my vague replies since I'm no expert in c#. Just trying to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: `futureProductPrice.SetValue("true");` instead of `futureProductPrice.SetValue("FutureProductPrice");`



Just as this example here:

`XElement root = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Child", "child content")
);
root.SetValue("new content");
Console.WriteLine(root);`


This example produces the following output:


`<Root>new content</Root>`

Comment: Thank you. But futureProductPrice is still null. I edit the post

Comment: I tried this too: new XElement("FutureProductPrice", true )

Comment: I have one last remark concerning the ambiguity of the name "FutureProductPrice": is it the XElement FutureProductPrice or the public boolean object FutureProductPrice? Consider renaming one. I probably cannot help you any further with my limited knowledge, but I'm sure someone else can. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the wrong root of the element. It has to be this:

```
  XElement futureProductPrice = settingsElement.Element("futureproductprice");
```